# Bamboo plan branching with different JDK version

Tags: bamboo

I'm working on bamboo, in the plan configuration there is a task to build a maven project (Maven 3.x configuration). When configuring plan branching is there a way to change the build JDK version for a specific branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, this is not possible as of now.
(see https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/67887/run-branchplan-with-different-build-configurations)

> No, it's not possible. Branches inherit build configuration from master, there are very few things that can be modified or overridden. You cannot create new Jobs or Tasks in Branches.

This is a shame as I imagine it is not uncommon to use Bamboo for various versions of your software which might have to be build with different JDKs.
A simple (but unsatisfactory) workaround is to clone a build plan and modify the tasks accordingly :(